# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpulse

Tags: 13.04, compiling

Can you help me to fix this issue. I try to compile Qt application but I always get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpulse
```

I know I have to install some libs I just don't know which one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq or -l<something>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148609/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lpq-or-lsomething)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [libpulse-dev [image: Install libpulse-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libpulse-dev).

#### How did I find that?

> ```
> cannot find -lpulse
> ```

Means you need the `pulse` *library* (remove the `-l` prefix in your head to see it). So here we have two keywords: `lib` and `pulse`.

To compile libraries into your own project you usually need header files or the static version of the library. These are included in the "development package" of libraries. In Ubuntu (and Debian) you'll find them in `-dev` suffixed package names.

So, then the first thing you do is find a package based on `lib`, `pulse` and `-dev`. And hey, it exists: `libpulse-dev`!

Alternatively, you can use the http://packages.ubuntu.com site to find packages which contain a certain file - in this case your linker was looking for `libpulse.so` file (read more about the GNU linker why this exact filename). By searching the file on that site you also see the package listed.