# Wine, compilation failed, need some advice

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, wine, compiling, patch

Sorry for my bad English.

I`m trying to compile **chrisbmrs** patched wine to support native D3D9: https://github.com/chrisbmr/wine/tree/d3dadapter9-wip. I've tried to follow tips from README file and I also tried to compile both **./tools/wineinstall** and **./configure**, but I constantly get errors:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/wine-d3dadapter9-wip/dlls/d3d9'
../../tools/winegcc/winegcc  -B../../tools/winebuild --sysroot=../.. -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -shared ./d3d9.spec buffer.o d3d9_main.o d3dadapter9.o device.o directx.o query.o shader.o stateblock.o surface.o swapchain.o texture.o vertexdeclaration.o volume.o       version.res    -o d3d9.dll.so  -ldxguid -luuid -ladvapi32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lwined3d  ../../libs/port/libwine_port.a   
d3d9_main.o: In function `DllMain':
/home/wine-d3dadapter9-wip/dlls/d3d9/d3d9_main.c:159: undefined reference to `d3dadapter9_destroy'
/home/wine-d3dadapter9-wip/dlls/d3d9/d3d9_main.c:154: undefined reference to `d3dadapter9_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
winegcc: gcc failed
make[1]: *** [d3d9.dll.so] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/wine-d3dadapter9-wip/dlls/d3d9'
make: *** [dlls/d3d9] Error 2

Compilation failed, aborting install.
```

or

```
configure: libOSMesa development files not found (or too old), OpenGL rendering in bitmaps won't be supported.
configure: libd3dadapter9 development files not found. Native Direct3D9 won't be supported.
configure: libhal development files not found, no legacy dynamic device support.
configure: libldap (OpenLDAP) development files not found, LDAP won't be supported.
```

Please, point me in the right direction. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

OS: Ubuntu13.04, GPU: nvidia 9200m, driver: nvidia xorg 313.

Answer (score 0):

Trying it myself right now, I'll letcha know how it goes.

Found this in the archives:
http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/mesa-dev/2013-July/041900.html

And it lead me to the d3dadapter mesa, which should include the missing libd3dadapter9:
https://github.com/chrisbmr/Mesa-3D/tree/gallium-nine

And there is also a link to the wine you already have in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing all build dependencies of Wine:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep wine
```

If that still does not satisfy all dependencies, you can try the approach as I posted in [/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpulse](https://askubuntu.com/a/320255/88802)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Ubuntu (I use Fedora 19), but it may still be helpful. I followed the guidance provided at this [link](http://github.com/chrisbmr/Mesa-3D/blob/gallium-nine/src/gallium/state_trackers/nine/README). However some steps are left behind. I'll try to provide more complete instructions:

1. Check the following:

   - Running `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer string"` should return something containing `Gallium`.
   - This answer assumes you have already installed (regular) Wine, this can be done by running `sudo apt-get install wine`.

     Running `wine --version` should return a version of `wine-1.6-rcX` or newer.
2. Install all build-dependencies for:

   - Mesa, to build gallium-nine:

     ```
     sudo apt-get build-dep mesa
     ```
   - Wine, to build wine-d3dadapter9:

     ```
     sudo apt-get build-dep wine
     ```
3. First, let's build and install the gallium-nine d3dadapter9:

   - Download [http://github.com/chrisbmr/Mesa-3D/archive/gallium-nine.zip](http://github.com/chrisbmr/wine/archive/d3dadapter9-wip.zip) and unpack the `Mesa-3D-gallium-nine` folder somewhere you can find it back, for example in your home directory.
   - Open a terminal in the unpacked `Mesa-3D-gallium-nine` folder and run to following commands:

     ```
     CFLAGS="-m32" CXXFLAGS="-m32" ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr \
     --with-gallium-drivers=nouveau,r600,swrast --enable-nine \
     --with-gallium-driver-dir="`pwd`/src/gallium/targets/pipe-loader/.libs" \
     --enable-debug --enable-texture-float --with-dri-drivers= --disable-dri \
     --disable-opengl --disable-egl --disable-vdpau --disable-xvmc --disable-gbm \
     --disable-gallium-llvm --enable-32bit --disable-64bit
      make
      sudo ln -s "\`pwd\`/lib/gallium/libd3dadapter9.so.0.0.0" /usr/lib/
      sudo ln -s "\`pwd\`/lib/gallium/libd3dadapter9.so.0" /usr/lib/
      sudo ln -s "\`pwd\`/lib/gallium/libd3dadapter9.so" /usr/lib/
      sudo ln -s "\`pwd\`/include/d3dadapter" /usr/include/
     ```
4. Then, we build and install the new Wine libraries:

   - Download the relevant wine-master branch at the following [link](http://github.com/chrisbmr/wine/archive/master.zip) and unpack the `wine-master` folder somewhere you can find it back, for example in your home directory.
   - Download [d3dadapter9-wip.zip](http://github.com/chrisbmr/wine/archive/d3dadapter9-wip.zip) and unpack all the contents of the `wine-d3dadapter9-wip` directory in the previously unpacked `wine-master` folder.
     Choose to overwrite the existing files.
   - Open a terminal in the `wine-master` folder and run to following commands:

     ```
     ./configure
     make
     for f in d3d9.dll gdi32.dll user32.dll wineps.drv winex11.drv;
     do
         sudo mv /usr/lib/wine/$f.so /usr/lib/wine/$f.so.old;
         sudo ln -s "\`pwd\`/dlls/\`basename -s .dll $f\`/$f.so" /usr/lib/wine/;
     done
     ```
5. Configure Wine to use nine:

   - Run `regedit`.
   - Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\Direct3D`.
     If it's not there, create it.
   - Create a new DWORD value called `UseNative`.
     Set its value to `1`.

For more information about using gallium-nine, look at the guidance provided at the first link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I used this trick,

Hope this helps you too guys,

go to your wine folder and edit the config file:
Open with your text editor.

Replace line:

```
LIBS="-lOSMesa $X_LIBS $X_PRE_LIBS $XLIB -lm $X_EXTRA_LIBS $LIBS"
```

with

```
LIBS="-lOSMesa -lGLU -lGL $X_LIBS $X_PRE_LIBS $XLIB -lm $X_EXTRA_LIBS $LIBS"
```

and add:

```
fi
if test "x$ac_cv_lib_soname_OSMesa" = "x"; then :
```

to:

```
fi
ac_cv_lib_soname_OSMesa=libOSMesa.so
if test "x$ac_cv_lib_soname_OSMesa" = "x"; then :
```

then save and try `./configure again`.